# How to access a public variable in another deployed instance of the same contract?

Tags: solidity

A function in contract `Escrow` needs to access a public variable of another deployment of the same contract `Escrow`. Here is the pseudo code of the function (not sure if the code below is going to work) :

```js
pragma "^0.7.0";
    
contract Escrow {
    uint256 public value;
    
    constructor () payable {
    ...
    }
    
    function getValueFromAnotherInstanceEscrow(address _anotherEscrowAddress) external returns 
    (bool) {
       Escrow _double = Escrow(_anotherEscrowAddress);  //legal? instance itself from inside of Escrow
       uint256 temp = _double.value();
       //do something with _double.value();  //<<== value is a public variable 
       return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible and legal. By casting an address to the contract instance you just tell them that you can use the public method of that contract to access this. In case that `_anotherEscrowAddress` is not actually an instance of `Escrow` the contract will most likely revert. Also you should pay attention to security if the address or the contract at the address is not under your control as it might influence your code (similar to how you should sanitize user input in any application).

External function calls are documented in the Solidity docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/control-structures.html#external-function-calls

Edit:

Another, maybe cleaner way, would be to extract an `Interface` for you escrow and use this one (see https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/contracts.html?#interfaces).

Comment: How to verify if the address passed in is for `Escrow` contract? There is a chance that a bogus address is passed in. The `value` returned has to be > 0 for sure. According to the doc, EVM treated function call to nonexistent contract a success. A bogus address will not throw error I assume.